# Wrap identifiers automatically with brackets in SSMS text editor

Tags: ssms

Working in SQL Server Management Studio, when using the text editor:

Is there any way to automatically wrap schema names, table names, column names and other identifiers with brackets so I don't have to put them manually, just in the same way it does it when it auto-generates queries? Is there (perhaps) any Intellisense feature I'm missing?

**EDIT**: see accepted answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Manngo I had column names containing whitespaces and SQL keywords so the brackets ensure the identifiers will be interpreted as such. It also helps me with readability.

Comment: That makes sense though I don’t think it makes it more readable, since it introduces a lot of clutter. I always think that column names which need delimiting are a product of bad design, though I don’t suppose you have much control over that if somebody else built the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the options given by @Shaulinator in his answer, ApexSQL Refactor does the job very nicely, integrates with SSMS and is free.

This is the particular option that I needed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no native function for this yet in SSMS. You can view the IntelliSense properties document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/configure-intellisense-sql-server-management-studio). You can download [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) and it has a built in formatting function.

[APEX](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) makes a paid formatting tool and there is another tool called [Poor Man's T-SQL](http://poorsql.com/). [RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/index) also makes a tool that is paid, all three work nicely. I am sure there are other tools out there too.

Comment: Hopefully MS will integrate some of these features one day. Will take a look to the suggestions.

Comment: APEX no longer has a fee tool

Comment: @LordDarthVader Did you mean with a fee or without a fee?

Answer (score 1):

there is a built in option:
Tools/Options/SQL Object Explorer/Commands --> Drag/Drop
Set Surround object names with brackets when dragged to False.

Comment: I found it set to `True` by default, and it only wraps identifiers when dragging the objects from the Object Explorer, not when typing their names which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The correct option path is Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Commands: Drag/Drop > Surround object names with brackets when dragged.